# How to verify that rsync copied the device correctly when copy-devices is enabled?

Tags: rsync, devices, disk-image

This is an extension to [Why rsync attempts to copy file that is already up-to-date?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85993/why-rsync-attempts-to-copy-file-that-is-already-up-to-date)

I'm attempting to use the `--copy-devices` patch to `rsync` to copy an entire disk drive and store it as an image on another machine.

The copy appears to have run correctly however, when I run `rsync` again with the same values, it appears to copy some of the data again every time.

I ran `rsync` with the verbosity turned up and got this:

```
$ sudo rsync -vvz --partial --progress --copy-devices /dev/sdb me@otherserver:/backupdisks/mydisk.img
opening connection using: ssh -l me otherserver rsync --server -vvze.Lsfx --partial --copy-devices . /backupdisks/mydisk.img  (11 args)
me@otherserver's password: 
delta-transmission enabled
sdb
320,071,851,520 100%   63.47MB/s    1:20:09 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)
total: matches=2441955  hash_hits=2441955  false_alarms=204015955 data=0

sent 188 bytes  received 21,979,001 bytes  2,837.31 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

I'm aware that rsync determines changes by time, but the disk has not changed between rsyncs (and how would it determine the modified time of a disk anyway?)  The time on the remote image, however, does get updated each time.  So this could be the issue.

The other possibility is that the disk has a bad sector which is returning a different value each time and negates whatever checksum is being used.

My question is two-fold:

1. **Has my image been transferred successfully and, if so, why does it appear to retransmit much of the disk if I run it again?**  (This may also be partly answered as part of my corollary question [What are "matches", "hash_hits", and "false_alarms" in rsync output, and does "data=0" mean success?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318937/what-are-matches-hash-hits-and-false-alarms-in-rsync-output-and-does-d) )
2. **Am I missing a switch to make this work properly?**  (Maybe `--checksum` ?)  Is it possible to list block-level failures used by the rsync algorithm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default rsync compares files by size and timestamp, but a device does not have a size so it must calculate differences using the delta algorithm which is described in this [tech report](https://rsync.samba.org/tech_report/node2.html).
 Loosely, the remote file is divided into blocks of a chosen size, and the checksums of these are sent back.  The local file is similarly checksummed in blocks, and compared with the list.  The remote is then told how to reassemble the blocks it has to remake the file, and data for the blocks that do not match is sent.

You can see this by asking for debug output at level 3 just for the deltasum algorithm with option `--debug=deltasum3`.  You can specify a block size with `-B` to simplify the numbers. For example, for a file that has already been copied once, a second run of

```
rsync -B 100000 --copy-devices -avv --debug=deltasum3 --no-W /dev/sdd /tmp/mysdd
```

produces output like this showing the checksum for each block:

```
count=164 rem=84000 blength=100000 s2length=2 flength=16384000
chunk[0] offset=0      len=100000 sum1=61f6893e
chunk[1] offset=100000 len=100000 sum1=32f30ba3
chunk[2] offset=200000 len=100000 sum1=45b1f9e5
...
```

You can then see it matching the checksums of the other device fairly trivially, since there are no differences:

```
potential match at 0      i=0 sum=61f6893e
match at 0      last_match=0      j=0 len=100000 n=0
potential match at 100000 i=1 sum=32f30ba3
match at 100000 last_match=100000 j=1 len=100000 n=0
potential match at 200000 i=2 sum=45b1f9e5
match at 200000 last_match=200000 j=2 len=100000 n=0
...
```

At the end the `data=` field is 0, showing no new data was sent.

```
total: matches=164  hash_hits=164  false_alarms=0 data=0
```

If we now corrupt the copy by overwriting the middle of the file:

```
echo test | dd conv=block,notrunc seek=80 bs=100000 of=/tmp/mysdd 
touch -r /dev/sdd /tmp/mysdd
```

then the rsync debug shows us a new checksum for block 80 but no match for it. We go from match 79 to match 81:

```
chunk[80] offset=8000000 len=100000 sum1=a73cccfe
...
potential match at 7900000 i=79 sum=58eabec6
match at 7900000 last_match=7900000 j=79 len=100000 n=0
potential match at 8100000 i=81 sum=eba488ba
match at 8100000 last_match=8000000 j=81 len=100000 n=100000
```

At the end we have `data=100000` showing that a whole new data block had to be sent.

```
total: matches=163  hash_hits=385  false_alarms=0 data=100000
```

The number of matches has been reduced by 1, for the corrupt block checksum which failed to match. Perhaps the hash hits rise because we lost sequential matching.

---

If we look [further](https://rsync.samba.org/tech_report/node6.html) in the same tech report, some test results are shown and the *false alarms*
are described as "the number of times the 32 bit rolling checksum matched but the strong checksum did not". Each block has a simple checksum and an md5 checksum made (md4 in older versions). The simple checksum is easy to search for using a hash table as it is a 32 bit integer. Once it matches an entry, the longer 16 byte md5 checksum is also compared, and if it does not match it is a false alarm, and the search continues.

My example uses a very small (and old) usb key device of 16Mbytes, and the minimum hash table size is 2**16 i.e. 65536 entries, so it is pretty empty when holding the 164 chunk entries I have. So many false alarms are normal and more an indication of efficiency then anything else.

Comment: I notice that in all of your example *false_alarms* = 0,  but in my example it's quite high (204015955).  Can you please include why that value would be high?  Would that cause data to be retransmitted?

Comment: I added a paragraph to the end of my answer. My example with 0 is the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You want to consider using `rsync --partial --inplace` as well as your other options, because otherwise it will make a full copy of the disc image at the destination side while it is working. I have been using `-B 4096` as well because it's the natural sector size of the device, and rsync default block size it too small for this type of operation.

To double-check that the image was all copied correctly I would suggest an indpendent `sha1sum` done at both the source and destination side. It should not be necessary, but if you want to be sure, that's simple and you can trust it. I am presuming that your source disk is not a live mount or anything nasty like that, otherwise all bets are off and there is no reliable method to send it.

Comment: I don’t understand your point. The OP ***wants*** to copy the disk image to the destination; why should they do something to prevent that?