# What are "matches", "hash_hits", and "false_alarms" in rsync output, and does "data=0" mean success?

Tags: rsync

This is a corollary question to [How to verify that rsync copied the device correctly when copy-devices is enabled?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318934/how-to-verify-that-rsync-copied-the-device-correctly-when-copy-devices-is-enable)

When reattempting a transfer (using the `--copy-devices`) flag and two levels of verbosity `-vv`, I got this output:

```
sudo rsync -vvz --partial --progress --copy-devices /dev/sdb me@otherserver:/backupdisks/mydisk.img
delta-transmission enabled
sdb
320,071,851,520 100%   63.47MB/s    1:20:09 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)
total: matches=2441955  hash_hits=2441955  false_alarms=204015955 data=0

sent 188 bytes  received 21,979,001 bytes  2,837.31 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

**What do the "matches", "hash_hits", and "false_alarms" values mean, and does "data=0" mean?**

**Has the transfer been successful or not?**

Comment: See my answer to your previous question that you link to.

Answer (score 0):

As per https://lists.samba.org/archive/rsync/2004-November/011057.html

`false_alarms` just tells you how many blocks had a matching weak checksum that did not match when the strong checksum was compared.

rsync only mentions this stat if debugging levels of verbosity are set