# Find out why rsync retransmits file

Tags: linux, osx, rsync

I want to backup a directory from a Linux server (reiserfs) onto an external HDD (hfs) attached to a MacBook running MacOSX 10.13.

It's Gentoo Linux and I have installed rsync version 3.1.2.
On MacOSX, I have installed rsync 3.1.2 via Homebrew.

Now, I use the flags `-aAxzPiv --delete-delay`. Earlier I also had `-X` but because of [this upstream rsync 3.1.2 bug](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/issues/568) I removed it. I connect as `root` to the Linux server to have all the rights to read everything and also run it as `sudo` on MacOSX. I.e. it is like this:

```
sudo rsync -aAxzPiv --delete-delay root@server:/mnt/data6 .
```

It mostly seems to work, except for a few directories/files which are always going to be retransmitted (in some cases deleted first and then transmitted, although I have `--delete-delay`). This is what I'm trying to resolve.

So, first question: Is there a nice flag for `rsync` which gives me the information why it thinks that it should retransmit/delete? There is `-v`, `--info`, `--debug` which might give me that, but what are the exact flags for those?
(*Edit: Thanks meuh, I added `-i` now, which helps a bit, although it is still limited.*)

I guess this is probably an issue that it didn't correctly preserved the time on the target file. Or maybe on a directory. E.g. I see this:

```
...
>f..t....... .../Documents/Topologische Spiele und resourcenbeschränkte Baire-Kategorie.pdf
    332,553 100%   15.86MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#87, ir-chk=1062/50500)
...
>f.st..g.... .../OpenLieroX/Tools/GameCompiler/src/main.cpp
     14,813 100%   14.13MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#88, ir-chk=1004/198016)
...
>f.st..g.... .../openlierox/tools/GameCompiler/src/main.cpp
      3,891 100%    3.71MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#95, ir-chk=1003/410613)
...
>f.st....... .../Robot/Main/uMainForm.o
    276,724 100%  330.77kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#93, ir-chk=1455/198859)
...
*deleting   .../Reise/SF2015/A1602080010(Zeyer).pdf
*deleting   .../Reise/SF2015/
...
.../Reise/SF2015/
.../Reise/SF2015/A1602080010(Zeyer).pdf
        126,218 100%  100.29kB/s    0:00:01 (xfr#566, ir-chk=1001/470897)
...
```

I guess there are multiple issues. E.g. `...resourcenbeschränkte...` might be an Unicode encoding issue. Then there is `openlierox` vs `OpenLieroX` which might be problematic because the target filesystem is case insensitive. I'm not sure how `rsync` should behave in this case of if it even has any special logic for this. Then, e.g. the file `uMainForm.o` is always retransmitted, for unknown reasons (but not deleted first). Then, the directory `SF2015` including all files is first deleted and then retransmitted.

About the directory which is being deleted. On the server, a `stat` on that directory gives me:

```
$ stat .../texte1
  File: '.../texte1'
  Size: 8664        Blocks: 17         IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 811h/2065d  Inode: 181281      Links: 45
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1002/      gz)   Gid: (  100/   users)
Access: 2016-07-21 03:19:33.000000000 +0200
Modify: 2016-02-06 18:58:10.000000000 +0100
Change: 2016-07-21 03:19:33.000000000 +0200
 Birth: -
```

On the Mac, I get this:

```
$ stat .../texte1
16777225 8884695 drwxr-xr-x 236 (1002) _lpoperator 0 8024 "Nov  4 14:06:39 2017" "Nov  4 14:02:07 2017" "Nov  4 14:02:07 2017" "Feb  6 18:58:10 2016" 4096 0 0 .../texte1
```

I guess it gets confused about the times.

So, next question: What flags should I use? Maybe I will resolve the case-insensitive issues by hand, by just renaming that on the source side (it should be rare). Maybe as well for the Unicode issues. But I don't exactly understand the deletions/retransmissions.

Also, maybe I should use another `rsync` version on MacOSX? The original MacOSX `rsync` is version 2.6.9 and has some other flags and I found that there are more problems but I'm not completely sure.

(Related is [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85993/why-rsync-attempts-to-copy-file-that-is-already-up-to-date) but it doesn't really answer my questions here. Also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/341413/see-only-changes-when-running-rsync).)

Comment: Use `--itemize-changes` (`-i`) to get details on why a file is updated.